# How to make a Matplotlib window (i) transparent, (ii) not having a window title bar (at least with Ubuntu/Unity)

Tags: matplotlib, ubuntu-unity

I want to plot a graph with Matplotlib and to keep updating it (reading values from a file as the file grows). I am using code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1713023/1711146) to dynamically read data from the file and it works.

Now I have two questions:

1. I would like to make the window displaying the figure transparent, so that the windows below it become visible. Setting alpha of figure.patch and axes.patch to 0 does not work, the window is still not transparent.
2. I would like to remove system title bar from the window. (I am using Ubuntu 13.04 with Unity).

In the end, I would like to have just a graph and, maybe, a bounding rectangle around it without anything else (or, with a semi-transparent black background).